# Chrome sometimes scrolls two "clicks"

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

Recently (in the last month or two maybe?) I've been having issues with scrolling in Chrome (and only Chrome; no other programs exhibit this problem!). Sometimes (usually after not scrolling for 10 seconds or so) when I scroll a single click on my mousewheel Chrome will move twice the distance it should. My brother also reported experiencing this recently. We both normally have smoothscroll disabled via a flag but he tried re-enabling it and still saw the problem.

Is this a known problem? Is there a known fix?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, furiously scrolling up and down a couple of times fixes the double-scroll for a short while, but it always comes back.

Comment: This is more often due to physical mouse issues than software.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Well I would have thought that, except that it only happens in Chrome. Additionally, the mouse is a Logitech G502, which uses a self-calibrating optical sensor so it can never wear out. I forgot to mention, furiously scrolling up and down a couple of times fixes the issue for a short while.

Comment: Optical sensor on the *scroll wheel*? Nice, and somewhat unusual.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Well by that I just mean it's a ring full of small spokes, and there's an IR light on one side and a sensor on the other. Presumably this is to allow the flywheel mode to work reliably. Photo: https://images.tweaktown.com/content/7/7/7748_23_logitech-g502-proteus-spectrum-rgb-tunable-gaming-mouse-review.jpg

Comment: Check for dust on the wheel and sensor.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You forgot the bit where it only happens in Chrome :P

Comment: Assuming this is not hardware (it _really_ sounds like hardware) I would suggest the issue is application latency. In video games this would be dropped frames and stuttering (not "lag" which is a networking issue). Basically, when you stop moving around in chrome, chrome decides that content off the edge of the screen can be removed from memory... then when you start scrolling there is a hesitation while chrome loads and re-renders the content. Scrolling furiously back and forth makes chrome update the screen repeatedly which convinces it it should pre-render more content. Mostly guessing.

Comment: The root problem is probably a lack of available system ram caused by the installation of programs which sit in memory even when you aren't using them. Windows PCs tend to collect such programs. And the lack of available ram makes chrome more aggressive about freeing ram up. This is all just a hypothetical... but it fits.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong I know it sounds like hardware but it's definitely not :P It's also not related to resource usage as far as I can see. I'm on a relatively powerful workstation PC here at work, with 32GB of ram, a hyperthreaded 4-core Xeon processor (an old model, but still fast enough) and a couple of 250GB SSDs. I also dedicate a lot of drive space to the pagefile, so my max commit is 95.8GB (out of which I am currently using 23.3GB). But most importantly, Chrome is actually moving the scrollbar two "clicks" worth of scroll, which should never be caused by...

Comment: ... content off-screen waiting to render (not least because rendering is threaded in Chrome, I believe). Additionally, my home PC and my brother's PC are also very powerful and we still see the issue there. I believe it is a Chrome bug, but I was hoping someone here might be able to link me to a bug report or provide me a workaround. That said, I haven't seen the issue since updating to m80 yesterday. If I see it again I'll be creating a bug report myself (though I have no clue how they'd fix it with the low repro rate....).

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with my Logitech G305 mouse, only in Chrome.

I disabled Fractional Scroll Offsets ( chrome://flags/#fractional-scroll-offsets ) and restarted Chrome, and haven't experienced the problem since.

I did once have the same issue a year or two ago so I'm unsure if this setting fixed it, or if the restart was enough.

Comment: You're right, it's the right flag for that sort of thing, but it has more to do with how the page you scroll down through was coded than anything else. I used to have that kind of issue with Chromium-based browsers in some webpages, that I didn't experience with Firefox. The former interprets page rendering in a stricter fashion, when Firefox paints the page based on screen size. One does threaded rendering, the other does vectorial, and that makes all the difference in some poorly-coded pages...

Comment: @Didier in my experience it happened on any page, even ones that didn't do any scrolling JavaScript stuff.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I haven't personally seen the problem for a long time but I think my brother might have so I'll get him to try this fix if he has.

Comment: It's not just about JavaScript or any derivative, it's just about how webpages are "painted" on your PC screen. Chrome treats each element or frame as a thread, that must be processed, then displayed, in full over the visible part of the page; Firefox treats those elements as shapes, and paints only the part that's visible on the canvas (the screen). That gives the illusion that Chrome is faster than Firefox at displaying webpages (sometimes it is, by a margin), but rendering is poor most of the time, with blurry fonts and badly aligned frames. Two different schools of technical thought...

Answer (score 0):

For any googlers facing this issue try disabling "Enable experimental prediction for scroll events" at (chrome://flags/#enable-resampling-scroll-events-experimental-prediction).

Mine would double scroll randomly and fix itself for a couple scrolls after I double clicked the middle mouse button. My prediction setting was "auto" and after switching it to "Disabled" I no longer have any issues with double scrolls.