# Double scrolling on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse-wheel

This isn't a "double scroll bar bug" that I've seen on here, this is something different.

To put it simply, sometimes for no reason at all scrolling on chrome will suddenly double. To best explain, I'll have to get a bit more specific. I read web novels often, and the use of the scroll wheel is self explanatory there. It happens seemingly at random, with no particular cause I can pinpoint. I'll be scrolling down through a chapter and then it'll double my scroll value. I scroll back up and it double scrolls up. If I repeat that process a few times, it'll go back to normal. But then it happen all over again a few seconds later.

Today I finally realized that a simple click anywhere on the page will make the double scrolling stop. Simple solution, but it's still very irritating and frequent. To run a test I opened a Firefox tab on my other monitor, and then kept reading on Chrome. As soon as the double scroll happened, I'd attempt to scroll on Firefox. It would single scroll on Firefox, then single scroll on Chrome again till the problem resurfaced a few seconds later.

So far I've looked through the settings on Chrome, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome sometimes scrolls two "clicks"](https://superuser.com/questions/1528628/chrome-sometimes-scrolls-two-clicks)

Comment: I read through the thread just now, and the solution mentioned is to disable chrome://flags/#fractional-scroll-offsets but when I checked, that setting didn't appear at all. I read through all of the settings by searching "scroll" but didn't find anything that appeared to be correct. The issue isn't currently happening so I can't just change them one by one till something works, and I'm at a loss.

Comment: Chrome is well-known for disappearing options. I have retracted my above vote for duplicate, but if the problem has disappeared then this post is without issue.

Comment: The problem comes and goes. I can solve it easily with a computer restart, but that's just treating the symptoms. It happened just yesterday when I made the post, and I'd like to prevent the future headaches.